# How to trigger some code when back from "Over Current Content" ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift4

There are two ViewController in my app, ViewController and ViewController2

In ViewController, a button set `Present Modally segue to "ViewController2"`

And ViewController override viewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    print("will appear")
}
```

In ViewController2, a button to go back

```
@IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now it still can trigger viewWillAppear then I go back to ViewController from ViewController2

If I change ViewController2's presentation from `Full Screen` to `Over Current Context`, `viewWillAppear` will not be triggered

How can I trigger some code when go back?

Comment: Use your second viewController's ViewDidDisappear/ViewWillDisappear to call a method in the first viewController. (Use protocol/delegates to achieve this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without giving up storyboard segues, but you nevertheless had to setup will/did Disappear handler in ViewCOntroller2:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
            (segue.destination as? ViewController2).onViewWillDisappear = {
                //Your code
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    var onViewWillDisappear: (()->())?

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        onViewWillDisappear?()
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: finally I choose this version, because this can keep the segues, but above code is not work. Xcode suggest me to fix to this, then the code is work. `if segue.destination is ViewController2 {` `(segue.destination as! ViewController2).onViewWillDisappear = {`

Comment: Next step, I have modified these two lines in ViewController2 `var onViewWillDisappear: ((_ backVal:Int)->())?` , `onViewWillDisappear?(1)`, How to read the value in here? `(segue.destination as! ViewController2).onViewWillDisappear = {}`

Comment: @CLSo `.onViewWillDisappear = { myVariable in ... }` alternatively you can use implicit parameter `$0`:  `.onViewWillDisappear = { print($0) }`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to handle this operation. Here is one, which I used to use.

```
// ViewController1
class ViewController1: UIViewController {


   @IBAction func presentOverCurrentContext(button: Button) {
        let vc2 = // instantiate ViewController2
        vc2.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        vc2.presentingVC = self   // use this variable 'presentingVC' to connect both view controllers
        self.present(vc2, animated: true)
   }

}


// ViewController2
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

   var presentingVC: UIViewController?  // use this variable to connect both view controllers
   @IBAction func close(button: Button) {

        // handle operation here
        presentingVC?.viewWillAppear(true)

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { 

            // or here
            // presentingVC?.viewWillAppear(true)
        })
   }

}
```

You can also use, your own method to reload view/viewcontroller, but `viewWillAppear` is common accessible method for all view controllers (as part of super class life cycle) hence you may not need to specify custom type of view controller for `presentingVC`

Answer (score 1):

While the answers so far provided do work I think it's a good idea to show how to do it using a protocol and delegate as that's a clean implementation which then also allows for further functionality to be added with minimal effort.

So set up a protocol like this:

```
protocol SecondViewControllerProtocol: class {
    func closed(controller: SecondViewController)
}
```

Setup the second view controller like this:

```
class SecondViewController {
    public weak var delegate: SecondViewControllerProtocol?

    @IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.delegate?.close(controller: self)
    }
}
```

Setup the first view controller like this:

```
class FirstViewController: SecondViewControllerProtocol {
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SecondViewControllerID",
            let secondViewController = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {
            secondViewController.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func closed(controller: SecondViewController) {
    // Any code you want to execute when the second view controller is dismissed
    }
}
```

Implementing it like this does what the original request was and allows for extra methods to be put in the protocol so that the FirstViewController can respond to other actions in the SecondViewController.

Note:

You might want to move the delegate method call into the closure of the dismiss handler so that you know the method is not called until the SecondViewController is actually gone (in case you try to present another view which would fail).  If that's the case you could do this:

```
@IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.delegate?.close(controller: self)
    }
}
```

In fact you could have a will and did methods and call them like this:

```
@IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
    self.delegate?.willClose(controller: self)
    self.dismiss(animated: true) {
        self.delegate?.didClose(controller: self)
    }
}
```

Which would allow you to do something immediately while the second controller is animating away and then know when it has actually gone.

Comment: I should put `protocol SecondViewControllerProtocol: class {` to new swift file or to ViewController file?

Comment: That's really up to you and your design but if it's not too big I would just put it in the same file as the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Best/Clean way to handle this scenario to use call back handler.

**Example Code**

```
typealias CloseActionHandler = ()-> Void
class TestController: UIViewController {
    var closeActionHandler: CloseActionHandler?
    func close(_ handler:@escaping CloseActionHandler) {
        self.closeActionHandler = handler
    }
    @IBAction func closeButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.closeActionHandler?()
    }
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func loadTestController(viewController: TestController) {
        viewController.close {
            //will be called when user will tap on close button
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would argue a better/cleaner method would be to implement a protocol and delegate method.  Saying something is the best is normally just an opinion.

Comment: You might be looking into articles https://medium.cobeisfresh.com/why-you-shouldn-t-use-delegates-in-swift-7ef808a7f16b. I think articles well explained why you should not use delegates. Being said that I prefer to say it better / cleaner

Comment: I've seen that article and it has some interesting and valid points however it's not very balanced.  For example it doesn't point out any disadvantages of using callbacks (everything has disadvantages).  For example in a delegate model you can create a weak reference to the delegate and bingo no retaining but with a callback that's harder and must be done for each method.  Secondly the protocol defines the function name and these must be used so it's clear in the adopting class but with callbacks the function names can be anything in the adopting class.  Plus delegates require one asignment.